# How can I allow the user to upload several files with a single upload action in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, file-upload, multi-upload

I want to allow a user to upload several files with one upload action. What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about ASP.net here?

Comment: can you ask to Nick's question?

Comment: I don't think the question deserves a downvote

Comment: Actually its unclear as to whether Danny is talking about ASP.net or WindowsForms so I believe it does deserve a down-vote.

Comment: ASP.NET C#, sorry if my title isn't clear

Comment: have not you found correct answer yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlashUpload.aspx

http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2009/10/02/asp.net-multiple-file-uploading.aspx

Answer (score 0):

C# code

```
public ActionResult Create( HttpPostedFileBase[] FileUpload)
{
//upload here
}
```

in javascript you must add dynamic file uploaders to form. but tou must give them same name as FileUpload. and when you will post form it will send all FileUploaders.

or you can look at this [ASPNET-MVC-ModelBinding-Multiple-File-Uploads-to-an-Array](http://www.heartysoft.com/post/2010/05/06/ASPNET-MVC-ModelBinding-Multiple-File-Uploads-to-an-Array.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Get the selected Files from your Filedialoge:

```
foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
```

and Upload them in a the Loop

Read the [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect.aspx)